# Migrating from Google Cloud Function V1 to Google Cloud Function V2

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I recently noticed Google Cloud Function V2. I noticed about the difference between their APIs https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/version-comparison. However, I'm wondering for function handler code (the code that handles the actual requests), do we need to change the handler code during migration, or is it backwards compatible ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

While Cloud Function gen2 has a superset of the capabilities of the previous generation, its syntax is not backwards compatible.

For example, here's an example of a trigger for the Realtime Database in the [initial version](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events):

```
exports.makeUppercase = functions.database.ref('/messages/{pushId}/original')
    .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
      ...
});
```

And here's an example for [gen2](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta/database-events):

```
const onwrittenfunctiondefault = onValueWritten("/user/{uid}", (event) => {
  // …
});
```

I find it easiest to navigate an upgrade by keeping the relevant definitions for both the original and gen2 versions open side by side.